# is it possible to force UIView to reload with some updated data during KIF UI tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, kif-framework

I am using KIF framework for some `UI` testing, and wondering is it possible to force UIView to reload(via calling some method in the view controller) during KIF `UI` tests......?

Let's say the I have a main view which is a UITableView has 5 data items, during KIF tests running, I want to call the `UITableViewController` methods to add some data items and call  `UITableView` reload to refresh the `UITableView`.

I tried the code below, it compiles with no error and can be run, just that can't observe any changes of the `UITableView`.

```
-(void)testReloadTableView
{
    [tester waitForTimeInterval:5];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tableviewController"];
    [self.vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self.vc addData] //a method to add some data
    [self.vc.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Is this the correct way to call view controller methods to update some data/view during KIF testing? Or do you have any suggestions to do this kind of testing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any of the methods in your application from within a KIF test. Therefore, the issue with your code is that it doesn't achieve your desired outcome. It doesn't have anything to do with the KIF framework as this same code wouldn't achieve the desired result outside of a KIF test either.

However, the purpose of the KIF framework is to *functionally* test an iOS application. That means, to test the interactions that the user would have with the application. During a functional test, you should add data by scripting functional interactions with the app in the same way that the user would add additional data to the app.

However, there would be user scenarios where data would be inserted automatically, such as when your application has updated data due to new information synced from a network service. If so, what I'd suggest you need first is a *unit test* to ensure that your table view updates correctly when the underlying data source is updated, with the network update mocked out with a method that supplies the data for the test. Once you've confirmed that code works correctly, you can use that method to simulate the same update for the functional test in KIF.

If it is simply that you want to take a short-cut in the functional tests, to jump straight to there already being data in the table so that you can functionally test it, I'd suggest it could be worth re-thinking. It is better to have the functional tests test the full functional path. What is possible is to create methods within your KIF test class that are not tests themselves but contain KIF tasks (wait for view, tap items on screen and so on) that are called within your tests. This enables you to re-use this code by calling it from more than one test if you have multiple tests that you want to run that start at a particular point in the application.